# compar.gee model 'rank-deficient model matrix' error

Tags: r

I have to make `compar.gee` model, but it gives an error back. My data frame is fullfilled, withouth any `NA`s. Here is the code:

```
 gee1<-compar.gee(vysvetlovana~mat[,5]+mat[,6]+mat[,7]+mat[,8]+mat[,10]+mat[,1
 1]+mat[,12]+mat[,13]+mat[,14]+mat[,15]+mat[,16]+mat[,17]+mat[,18]+mat[,19]+ma
 t[,20]+mat[,21]+mat[,22]+mat[,23]+mat[,24]+mat[,25]+mat[,26]+mat[,27]+mat[,28
 ]+mat[,29]+mat[,30]+mat[,31]+mat[,32]+mat[,33]+mat[,34]+mat[,35]+mat[,36]+mat
 [,37]+mat[,38]+mat[,39]+mat[,40]+mat[,41]+mat[,42]+mat[,43]+mat[,44]+mat[,45]
 +mat[,46]+mat[,47]+mat[,48]+mat[,49]+mat[,50]+mat[,51]+mat[,52]+mat[,53]+mat[
 ,54]+mat[,55]+mat[,56]+mat[,57]+mat[,58]+mat[,59]+mat[,60]+mat[,61]+mat[,62]+
 mat[,63]+mat[,64]+mat[,65]+mat[,66]+mat[,67]+mat[,68]+mat[,69]+mat[,70]+mat[,
 71]+mat[,72]+mat[,73]+mat[,74]+mat[,75]+mat[,76]+mat[,77]+mat[,78]+mat[,79]+m
 at[,80],phy=tree,family=binomial(link="logit"))

 Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
 Error in gee(vysvetlovana ~ mat[, 5] + mat[, 6] + mat[, 7] + mat[, 8]   +  : 
 rank-deficient model matrix
```

Comment: try fitting this in `lm` and see which coefficients come back as `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! I tried it.

There are some `NA`´s in variables, which are probably here because of hight correlation of some variables.